# Marshal.Copy() не копирует последний байт

Tags: c#

Данную структуру:

```
struct struct_1
{
    public static byte __TYPE;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string string_1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 255)]
    public string string_2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string string_3; // тут например "1234567890abcdef"

    public byte GetTypeStruct()
    {
        return __TYPE;
    }
}
```

Я передаю в эту функцию:

```
public static byte[] getBytes(T str)
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
    byte[] arr = new byte[size+1];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 1, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    arr[0] = str.GetTypeStruct();
    return arr;
}
```

Массив **arr** всегда возвращается с нулевым байтом в последнем элементе, т.е. при обратном преобразовании, **string_3** получает не "*1234567890abcdef*", а "*1234567890abcde*". Помогло изменение количества элементов:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 17)]
public string string_3;
```

Но проблема скорее всего не в этом.

Comment: Цитата из [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2):  _Тип ByValTStr используется для встроенных массивов символов фиксированной длины, расположенных в структуре. Другие типы применяются к ссылкам на строки, включенным в структуры, содержащие указатели на строки._ У вас не массив, а строка.

Comment: Используйте массив char вместо string если вам такие правила преобразования (ASCIIZ) не подходят.